# Taylor-expansion for a limit expression on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: analysis

Say $$f(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi{}x)}-\sum\limits_{k\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\frac{1}{(x-k)^2}.$$ And $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$.

Prove by the Taylor-expansion of $x\mapsto \sin(\pi{}x)$ in $0$ that

$$\lim_{x\to{0}} f(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}-2\cdot{}\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{n^2}.$$

I see what happens with the summation. But I can not understand why the Taylor-expansion of $\sin(\pi{}x)$ generates the $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$-factor.

Can somebody help me? Thanx in advance!

Comment: I removed $x\ne0$ from the limit subscript. The definition of $\lim_{x\to0}$ automatically excludes $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you overlooked the $k=0$ term in the sum. We have
$$
f(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi{}x)}-\sum_{k\in{\mathbb{Z}}}\frac{1}{(x-k)^2} = \bigg( \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi{}x)} - \frac1{x^2} \bigg) -\sum_{\substack{k\in{\mathbb{Z}} \\ k\ne 0}}\frac{1}{(x-k)^2}.
$$
The limit as $x\to0$ of the last sum is indeed $2\sum_{k\ge1} 1/n^2$. As for the function in parentheses:
$$
\sin^2(\pi x) = \pi^2 x^2 - \frac{\pi^4}3 x^4 + O(x^6),
$$
and so
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi{}x)} - \frac1{x^2} &= \frac{\pi^2x^2-\sin^2(\pi x)}{x^2\sin^2(\pi x)} \\
&= \frac{\pi^2x^2-(\pi^2 x^2 - \frac{\pi^4}3 x^4 + O(x^6))}{x^2(\pi^2 x^2 + O(x^4))} \\
&= \frac{\frac{\pi^4}3 + O(x^2)}{\pi^2 + O(x^2)},
\end{align*}
whose limit as $x\to 0$ equals $\frac{\pi^2}3$.